# Change the language on Map control on Windows Phone 8

Tags: dictionary, windows-phone-8, here-api

When I change the language of the phone to any language (say French), the labels in the map change to French.

Is it possible to force a language in Map Control? I tried to use "Language" property of the Map and change it to "fr" & "fr-FR". It didnt work.

Comment: i'm sorry my understanding was that you wanna change given text

Comment: What do you mean by labels? Are you referring to street names and such or something else?

Comment: Yes, the street names the cities ... etc. If you change the language of the phone itself, you get them. But I dont want the user to change the system's language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually it's quite simple

if you wanna change the global language:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {                      
           Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
           Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");          
        }

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
        {                     
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");          
        }
```

if you wanna to get single resource:

```
CultureInfo c = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
var m = AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString(AppResources.MapControlTitle,c));
```

where `AppResourse` is your resource (resx) file, and `AppResources.MapControlTitle` is the label that wanna get.

happy coding (:

**EDIT**

can you try this:

> Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
>               YourMapControl.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);

Comment: Did you try that on the Map control? it didnt work for me at all

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the current Culture of the Thread.

Try to reinitialize the culture

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CH"); // For French Language ( or "fr-FR" )
```

before your Map Control Initialization.

In Theory, The Thread will be Reinitialized with the french Culture. ^^

Comment: Okay, Sorry for the "not-help" . If you find solution, please, share it :) I'm interested :)

Comment: I'm not sure, that your answer is here [Nokia Map Website](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Portal:Windows_Phone_Location_%26_Maps) but it's the official webSite for Nokia Map developper.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you were hoping for, but the Map Control will *always* honor the operating system's locale settings.

Comment: Can you get me an msdn link or something?

Comment: That's the point, there isn't any. This is by design. Unlike on a PC, for many reasons - namely privacy and security reasons, it's impossible to override a multitude of operating system settings (including locale) in the WP8 world.